# Symfony saving locale in session

Tags: symfony, session

I have two translation languages: en and ru

I have locale: en|ru in parameters.yml and translator:      { fallbacks: "%locale%"} in config.yml.

I need to do switching of languages. I need to save locales into session and set the right locale in parameters.yml. How i change locale parameter value to the right one from session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters.yml is not designed for dynamic content, but I think what you want to you need is this:

To get the currently set locale:

```
$locale = $request->getLocale();
```

To set the preferred locale order:

```
$session = $this->get('session');
$session->setLocale($request->getPreferredLanguage(array('de', 'en')));
```